# KCFinder in CKEditor showing HTTP 500 error on hosting server

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one of my Codeigniter v3.1.3 project, i have used 'KCFinder' in CKEditor for uploading images to the server. The directory structure of my localhost version of the project is:

```
localhost/project_ci
--application
--assets
----admin
------ckeditor
------kcfinder
--system
--index.php
```

Initially i was having difficulty integrating KCFinder with CKEditor but after searching the internet, i came across a tutorial(i don't rember the url now) explaining the steps to integrate it.I followed the steps mentioned there and now it works perfectly on localhost.The step1 of the said tutorial was to change some values of index.php in the root directory as:

```
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system';

$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application';
```

Now i have uploaded the above project in a Shared Hosting server.In the hosting server, the files are organized as follows:

```
/home/myaccount
--ci_top_secret
----application
----system
--public_html
----assets
----index.php
```

and the system_path values in index.php are:

```
$system_path = '../ci_top_secret/system';

$application_folder = '../ci_top_secret/application';
```

My website works well, all the CKEditor's are visible.However in the 'image properties' popup when i click the 'Browse Server' button, a **blank page** appear showing HTTP 500 error.Hence i am not able to upload images to the remote server.I really don't understand what is wrong.Is it because of the system_path values in the index.php.Please advise with some code.Thanks

Comment: somebody please have a look at my problem

Answer (score 0):

Inside KC-Finder you will find the folder conf folder
keep these file
config.php

```
<?php

/** This file is part of KCFinder project
  *
  *      @desc Base configuration file
  *   @package KCFinder
  *   @version 3.12
  *    @author Pavel Tzonkov <sunhater@sunhater.com>
  * @copyright 2010-2014 KCFinder Project
  *   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0 GPLv3
  *   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0 LGPLv3
  *      @link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com
  */

/* IMPORTANT!!! Do not comment or remove uncommented settings in this file
   even if you are using session configuration.
   See http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/install for setting descriptions */
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost' || strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '172.16')) {
    $upload_url = "upload";
    $upload_dir = "";
} else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "216.55.169.45") {
    $upload_url = "http://216.55.169.45/~mpdriver/master/assets/admin/kcfinder/upload";
    $upload_dir = "/home/mpdriver/public_html/master/assets/admin/kcfinder/upload";
} else {
    $upload_url = "upload";
    $upload_dir = "";
}
$_CONFIG = array(


// GENERAL SETTINGS

    'disabled' => FALSE,
    'uploadURL' => "upload",
    'uploadDir' => "",
    'theme' => "default",

    'types' => array(

    // (F)CKEditor types
        'files'   =>  "",
        'flash'   =>  "swf",
        'images'  =>  "*img",

    // TinyMCE types
        'file'    =>  "",
        'media'   =>  "swf flv avi mpg mpeg qt mov wmv asf rm",
        'image'   =>  "*img",
    ),


// IMAGE SETTINGS

    'imageDriversPriority' => "imagick gmagick gd",
    'jpegQuality' => 90,
    'thumbsDir' => ".thumbs",

    'maxImageWidth' => 0,
    'maxImageHeight' => 0,

    'thumbWidth' => 100,
    'thumbHeight' => 100,

    'watermark' => "",


// DISABLE / ENABLE SETTINGS

    'denyZipDownload' => false,
    'denyUpdateCheck' => false,
    'denyExtensionRename' => false,


// PERMISSION SETTINGS

    'dirPerms' => 0755,
    'filePerms' => 0644,

    'access' => array(

        'files' => array(
            'upload' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'copy'   => true,
            'move'   => true,
            'rename' => true
        ),

        'dirs' => array(
            'create' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'rename' => true
        )
    ),

    'deniedExts' => "exe com msi bat cgi pl php phps phtml php3 php4 php5 php6 py pyc pyo pcgi pcgi3 pcgi4 pcgi5 pchi6",


// MISC SETTINGS

    'filenameChangeChars' => array(/*
        ' ' => "_",
        ':' => "."
    */),

    'dirnameChangeChars' => array(/*
        ' ' => "_",
        ':' => "."
    */),

    'mime_magic' => "",

    'cookieDomain' => "",
    'cookiePath' => "",
    'cookiePrefix' => 'KCFINDER_',


// THE FOLLOWING SETTINGS CANNOT BE OVERRIDED WITH SESSION SETTINGS

    '_normalizeFilenames' => false,
    '_check4htaccess' => true,
    //'_tinyMCEPath' => "/tiny_mce",

    '_sessionVar' => "KCFINDER",
    //'_sessionLifetime' => 30,
    //'_sessionDir' => "/full/directory/path",
    //'_sessionDomain' => ".mysite.com",
    //'_sessionPath' => "/my/path",

    //'_cssMinCmd' => "java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor.jar --type css {file}",
    //'_jsMinCmd' => "java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor.jar --type js {file}",

);

?>
```

and also check your URL Pointings also.